# Add similar IFS function to query with sub-query (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

This is part of my query. I want to add another column called Missed if impact label is 1 and hours > 8 -> missed, impact 2 hours > 14 -> missed , impact 3 hours > 80 -> missed. Please help. Thanks!

```
  select
  o.create_datetime
  ,o.resolved_datetime
  ,24 * (to_date(resolved_datetime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
             - to_date(create_datetime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')) as hours 
  ,o.item
  ,o.impact_label

from
  (select 

      ,to_char(create_date,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') as create_datetime
      ,to_char(resolved_date,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') as resolved_datetime
      ,status
      ,(case impact_label
        when '1 - ' then '1'
        when '2 - ' then '2'
        when '3 - ' then '3'
        when '4 - ' then '4'
        when '5 - ' then '5'
        else null
        end) as impact_label

from   
        table )o
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd re-write that slightly using "with" clauses, but that's just me .. :) You likely need another layer in there to user the already calculated columns ...

Try something like this:

```
  with w_o as (
     select 
        ,to_char(create_date,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') as create_datetime
        ,to_char(resolved_date,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') as resolved_datetime
        ,status
        ,(case impact_label
          when '1 - ' then '1'
          when '2 - ' then '2'
          when '3 - ' then '3'
          when '4 - ' then '4'
          when '5 - ' then '5'
          else null
          end) as impact_label
        from   
          table
        ),
     w_sub as (
           select
              o.create_datetime
             ,o.resolved_datetime
             ,24 * (to_date(resolved_datetime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
                        - to_date(create_datetime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')) as hours 
             ,o.item
             ,o.impact_label
           from w_o
        )
  select create_datetime,
         resolved_datetime,
         hours,
         item,
         impact_label,
         case when impact_label = '1' and hours > 8
                 then 'missed'
              when impact_label = '2' and hours > 14
                 then 'missed'
              when impact_label = '3' and hours > 80
                 then 'missed'
              else
                 'hit?'
           end  missed
  /
```

This is the new part, rest is the same as what you have, just re arranged into WITH clauses .. ;)

```
         case when impact_label = '1' and hours > 8
                 then 'missed'
              when impact_label = '2' and hours > 14
                 then 'missed'
              when impact_label = '3' and hours > 80
                 then 'missed'
              else
                 'hit?'
           end  missed
```

You could also combine the case clauses using OR, however, this is probably clearer to read and follow ... so either way ...

Comment: With is wonderful! Thanks a lot for this, I created another layer and it works perfectly fine now!